# Calculator with % function

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

I want to add a "%" function to my calculator. I'm lost however.  Any suggestions will be helpful.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var inputs = [""];

    var totalString;

    var tempNum;

    var operators1 = ["+", "-", "/", "*"];

    var operators2 = ["."];

    var operators3 = ["%"];

    var num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

    function getValue(input) {
        if (operators1.includes(inputs.length - 1) === true && inputs === ".") {
            alert("Duplicate '.' ");
        } else if (inputs.length == 1 && operators1.includes(input) === false) {
            inputs.push(input);
        } else if (operators2.includes(inputs[inputs.length - 1]) === false) {
            inputs.push(input);
        } else if (num.includes(Number(input))) {
            inputs.push(input);
        }
        update();
    }

    function update() {
        totalString = inputs.join("");
        $("#display").html(totalString);
    }

    function getTotal() {
        totalString = inputs.join("");
        $("#display").html(eval(totalString));
    }

    $("a").on("click", function() {
        if (this.id === "clearAll") {
            inputs = [""];
            update();
        } else if (this.id === "clearLast") {
            inputs.pop();
            update();
        } else if (this.id === "total") {
            getTotal();
        } else if (this.id === "%") {
            tempNum = inputs.join("");
            var percent = Math.floor(totalString * (tempNum / 100));
            update();
        } else {
            if (inputs[inputs.length - 1].indexOf("+", "-", "/", "*", ".")) {
                getValue(this.id);
            } else {
                getValue(this.id);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Everything else works fine I'm just having difficulty figuring out where and how I can group the data so I can do the calculation.  Everything I've tried so far either only adds a 0 to the inputs array or returns a NaN result.

Comment: Can you post the HTML part of this? It would be even better if you could create a snippet in the question. That's available under the `<>` menu.

Comment: `<div id="calc">
<div id="calcHead">
<h3>Bat-Calculator V1.02</h3>
<div class="container-fluid" id="displayOutput">
<span class="container-fluid" id="display">0</span>
</div>
<br/>
</div>
<div id="calcBody">
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="1">1</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="2">2</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="3">3</a>
<a class="btn btn-warning" id="%">%</a>
<br/>
</div>
</div>
</center>
</body>`

Comment: That's about the just of it... sorry it's a bit jumbled... still getting use to this forum :P.

Comment: I am not sure how that is working. Can you create a snippet in the question or a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackBat023/nkabhmw3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You got a simple and complete example here : you try to do what this operator just do by himself % just add operator properly.

```
screen.innerHTML = output.concat(operator);
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGYpXE

Comment: Adding the operator isn't the problem, it's displaying the result in the $("#display") element after I do the equation that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
} else if (this.id === "%") {
            tempNum = inputs.join("");
            var percent = Math.floor(totalString * (tempNum / 100));
            inputs.push(percent);
            update();
```

I think you missed `inputs.push(percent);`

Why don't use `percent`?

Comment: Tried it ... that's the method that results in a "NaN" response.

Answer (score 0):

a - number
b- percent
result - b% from a

Code:

**a=34;

b=57;

result=a*(b/100)**

It is easy to do

Comment: I'm aware of how to calculate percentages, my problem is to let my code print out the correct result to the DOM.  My problem is extracting them from the inputs array correctly so I can use them in the calculation and output the result to the DOM.